# How to write an Android background service which never stops and keeps my variables values when I close my application?

Tags: android, variables, service

I have to write an Android background service which never stops and keeps my variables alive.

Here is my service:

```
public class PollingService extends Service {
    public static final String TAG = PollingService.class.getSimpleName();
    public static int alap = 0;

    public PollingService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "BIND");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "UNBIND");
        return true;
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        public PollingService getService() {
            return PollingService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                alap = alap+1;
                Log.d(TAG, ": "+alap+"");

                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "DESTROY");
    }
}
```

This is a counter service and it works well when my app is running, but when I close the app my variable "alap" start counting again from zero. 
I bind and unbind when I navigate from an Activity to another, but I need my variables values when I close the app.

Comment: *never stop* this is not possible

Comment: why don't you create a local database, write the values you want and each time you start the app your app will read those values

Comment: Actually , if it’s just an int , use SharedPreferences. No need for a Service (that is not going to work anyway). If there are more complex objects, you’ll have to rethink your strategy or implement a disk cache.

Comment: Why dont you use sharedPreferences to store your session data.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to use the method startForeground() in your service. Try something like this:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    startForeground(1, new Notification());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to store your variable value in "SharedPreference" in onDestory function.

```
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                alap = sharedpreferences.getString("alap",null);
                alap = alap+1;
                Log.d(TAG, ": "+alap+"");

                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //storing data
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("alap", alap);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d(TAG, "DESTROY");
    }
```